# Bridge not there in Google Earth

Tags: google-earth

In Google Earth, the Rio Grande Gorge Bridge is not there. They've got the road going in and out of the canyon. This would be a blast to drive, but there really is a bridge there. They had to have purposely taken it out. Why?
Lat/long: 36.476176° -105.732763°

Edit: Same applies for:
Royal Gorge Bridge in Canon City, Colorado.
Lat/long: 38.461088°-105.325118°

New River Gorge Bridge in Victor, WV
38.066808°, -81.082553°

Comment: Can you include a screenshot? I can see it in Google Maps aerial view.

Comment: Google Earth, not Maps.

Comment: Call Google!!! https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088?hl=en

Comment: In Bing Maps, the bridge looks a bit strange: http://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&cp=q2cq4v65p1z8&lvl=17&sty=o&form=LMLTCC - Maybe Google were ashamed of their own georeferencing work ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bridge is there both in the image but draped over google earth terrain and as a 3D structure.  **Turn on 3D building**.

Note that Google does not allow users to upload their 3D models (previously possible to create and upload with SketchUp a tool now owned by Trimble). The existing 3D buildings and structures have not (YET) been removed, but now new user-built buildings are being added.

[image]

Google, i think, has some other plans for their own data-driven and automated 3D modelling instead; Google imagery, terrain and data resolution differ from a place to place. Some areas may have extremely high resolution imagery featuring 3D objects created from LiDAR or stereo imagery whereas other areas are still Landsat 7 15 m resolution.

Only some pleaces feature this new 3D Google Earth technology, Sudbury, ON, Canada is for some reason one of them, I think most urban areas in the US are the same but the rest of the world will have to wait:

[image]

Comment: Google has gotten pretty crafty at using lidar data (or other high resolution elevation data) to give the appearance of 3D modeled buildings in some areas.  You can check to see what is the case in a particular area by checking/unchecking the "Terrain" box in layers and the "3D Buildings".

Comment: Apparently they also purchased SKybox Imaging.  I wonder if owning such satellite and getting on demand high res images from various angles helps them to generate terrain from stereo.

Comment: Excellent answer, and this explains the "road going in and out of the canyon" part of the question -- I thought it was just entering the canyon, then blank, then continuing on the other side!

Comment: At least it looks better than what bing offers...